# why spring boot data jpa update database field While the update function is not called

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I work on a spring boot data jpa web application,
in my controller class (I use thymeleaf for frontend) when i get my attribute field from database, then if the relatedTo filed is null, i valued it a temporary value to handling some things and conditions in thymeleaf:

`Attribute attribute=attributeService.getAttributeById(attrId); if(attribute.getRelatedTo()==null) attribute.setRelatedTo(new Attribute(-1));`

but this line  "attribute.setRelatedTo(new Attribute(-1));" causes an update operation in database by data jpa while i don't called update yet! and get this foreign key error because of attribute with id=-1 does not exist.
`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`attribute`, CONSTRAINT` attribute_ibfk_2 `FOREIGN KEY (`related_to`) REFERENCES` attribute `(`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)`

why is this happening?
thanks.

i got this error before in another case and try to change my code to avoid this, but i want to find the reason of this functionality of jpa to handle similar cases in future.

Comment: [AUTO flush](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-auto)

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov thanks, can u describe it in a simple word please? and is there any way to off this mode? set it to off causes problem?

Comment: you may disable that either for specific query via query hint: `@QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.FLUSH_MODE, value = "COMMIT") })` or globally via specifying `spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=COMMIT` in application.properties, however that may drastically change application behaviour, I would suggest to store temporary data in `@Transient` fields